# Working with vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

Complicated question, probably simple answer. So the program I need to make cannot include any library other than String, iostream, and vector. I need to create a program that has 3 functions. One that creates an integer vector, one that reverses a vector, and one that prints a vector. In order to take in values I need to use getline to intake a string, if the string states quit, we stop putting new values into it. Other wise we need to test if its an integer(positive or negative) and add it to the vector. My code is starting to get complicated so I really need some help. Below is what i have so far. I'm also using Visual Studio, if that matters. Thanks for any help in advance! The question I have is when I run the program, it will only output the first digit. I don't know why and would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> CreateVector()
{
    string tempvariable;
    bool quit = false;
    vector<int> userinput;
    cout << "Please enter in an integer, type 'quit' to exit " << endl;
    while (!quit)
    {
        getline(cin, tempvariable);
        if (tempvariable == "quit")
            quit = true;
        else
        {
            bool isaninteger = true;
            for(int i = 1; i <= tempvariable.size(); i++)
            {
                if (tempvariable[i] = "-" || isdigit(tempvariable[i]))
                    continue;
                else
               {
                    cout << "You entered in an incorrect option, please enter in a correct option" << endl;
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore();
                    isaninteger = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isaninteger)
                userinput.push_back(stoi(tempvariable));
            cout << "Please enter in an integer, type 'quit' to exit " << endl;
        }
    }
    return userinput;
}
void printVector(vector<int> userinput)
{
    int amountofspots = userinput.size();
    cout << "Your Vector is ";
    for (int i = 0; i < amountofspots; i++)
    {
        if (i = (amountofspots - 1))
            cout << userinput.at(i) << endl;
        else
            cout << userinput.at(i) << " , ";
    }
}
void reverseVector(vector<int>& userinput)
{
    int amountofspots = userinput.size();
    vector<int> tempvector;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountofspots; i++)
        tempvector.push_back(userinput.at(amountofspots - i));
    for (int i = 0; i < amountofspots; i++)
        userinput.pop_back();
    for (int i = 0; i < amountofspots; i++)
        userinput.push_back(tempvector.at(i));
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> CreatedVector = CreateVector();
    printVector(CreatedVector);
    reverseVector(CreatedVector);
    printVector(CreatedVector);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your question? It sounds like you basically want us to rewrite your code.

Comment: And?  I don't see a question in there.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statements are causing the issue?  You did run the debugger and viewed variables, didn't you?

Comment: If I run the program without running reverseVector I don't receive any warnings or error's until i enter in a negative integer. But, for example, if I enter 10, then quit, it outputs You Vector is 1 which should say 10.

Comment: I would have expected a few warnings on the usage of = in a conditonal.

Comment: There are quite a few warnings in this online compiler :http://ideone.com/ETavji

Comment: If you don't even know the basics (such as the difference between `=` and `==` and between `'-'` and `"-"`), then you shouldn't attempt more complicated tasks. First get the basic right. Seems the course is too advanced for you.

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that you've actually posted complete, compilable example code to showcase your problem. Most beginners unfortunately fail to do so. Good job! Even if the question itself is arguable a very basic one, you've made it easy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change `if (i = (amountofspots - 1))` to `if (i == (amountofspots - 1))` in the loop in `printVector()`.
2. Change `tempvariable[i] = "-"` to `tempvariable[i] == '-'` in `CreateVector()`.

`=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the comparison operator. Also, single characters are surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: I tried that, when I enter in 10 and then quit I still only receiving 1

Comment: Also  change `tempvariable[i] = "-"` to `tempvariable[i] == '-' `

Comment: When I change tempvariable[i] == "-" it outputs an error. I think it needs to be only = ? Or is 1 string character just a char and I should do '-'

Comment: A single = is an assignment not a check to see if the two are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverseVector(vector<int>& userinput)
{
    int amountofspots = userinput.size();
    vector<int> tempvector;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountofspots; i++)
        tempvector.push_back(userinput.at(amountofspots - i));
```

should probably be

```
void reverseVector(vector<int>& userinput)
{
    int amountofspots = userinput.size();
    vector<int> tempvector;
    for (int i = 1; i < amountofspots+1; i++) // Index error
        tempvector.push_back(userinput.at(amountofspots - i));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm pretty sure vectors start a 0 and size would return the amount of elements. So in the case there are four elements it would be 0,1,2,3 but the size would be 4. In that case the loops should work correctly wouldn't it?

Comment: @AaronJamesRasmussen: Indeed, element indices are 0,1,2,3 and size is 4. But note how the index passed to `at()` is `amountofspots - i`. So the indices in the loop will be 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, 4-4, i.e. 3,2,1,0.

Comment: Again you help heckl, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following:

> ```
>         for(int i = 1; i <= tempvariable.size(); i++)
>         {
>             if (tempvariable[i] = "-" || isdigit(tempvariable[i]))
> ```

Must become:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < tempvariable.size(); i++)
        {
            if (tempvariable[i] == '-' || isdigit(tempvariable[i]))
```

Explanation:

- String indices start from *0* and end at *size() - 1*.
- `[i]` returns a single `char`. `"-"` is not a single `char` but an entire string literal. You cannot directly compare a single `char` with an entire string. `-`, however, is a single `char`, so that comparison will work.
- `=` is not comparison but assignment. `==` is used for comparison. As your compiler should have warned you!

---

Note that there are further problems with your code:

> ```
>    if (i = (amountofspots - 1))
> ```

You are again mixing assignment and comparison. Make that `==`. And pay attention to compiler warnings!

And finally, `isdigit` is not exactly a great function. In order to really use it correctly, you'd first have to cast the operand to `int` and at the same time make sure it is not an invalid value, as documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Why don't you just catch the exception thrown by `stoi` if the specified string cannot be parsed?

Comment: Thanks so much I though String indicies started at 1(it actually says that in a slide by my professor >.<. The other people helped me with the rest like double equals and the single quote over '-'. Again thank you so much.

Comment: @AaronJamesRasmussen: Seriously? If your teacher *really* thinks that string indices start at 1, then I'd say he or she has never written a single C++ (or C, or Java, or C#, or PHP, or whatever) program in his or her whole life... :)